# как сделать переход линии(подчеркивания, типо border) от ссылке к ссылке в навигации?

Tags: html, css

Мне понравился эффект перехода подчеркивания (линии снизу) от одного элемента к другому. Однако я не знаю, как сделать такой переход. Можете объяснить? Заранее спасибо. У меня есть заготовка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, Ваш запрос. Вам нужно, чтобы у посещенной ссылки не было подчеркивания, а у не посещенной было?

Comment: Вот так: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2AOXBeVrgI. Хотя я бы иначе делал...

Comment: @darinkapoznyak, скольжение подчёркивания он хочет - как на ютьюбе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Снова гадать, но почему-то мне кажется, что автор хочет вот такую реализацию:

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu')

if(menu.length > 0) {
    menu.forEach(el => {
        const effect = el.querySelector('.menu__effect')
        const active = el.querySelector('.menu__item--active')

        const RecalcEffect = target => {
            effect.style.left = target.offsetLeft+'px'
            effect.style.width = target.offsetWidth+'px'
        }

        el.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
            const target = event.target.closest('.menu__item')
            if(target) RecalcEffect(target)
        })

        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            if(active)
                RecalcEffect(active)
            else {
                const left = +(effect.style.left.replace('px', ''))
                const width = +(effect.style.width.replace('px', '')) / 2
                effect.style.left = left+width+'px'
                effect.style.width = ''
            }
        });

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            if(active) RecalcEffect(active)
        })

        if(active) RecalcEffect(active)
    })
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/* То, что нужно ниже :) */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.menu__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu__item:hover,
.menu__item--active {
  color: #f00;
}

.menu__effect {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-property: width, left;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Один</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Два</a>
  <a class="menu__item menu__item--active" href="#">Три</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Четыре</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Пять</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Шесть</a>
  <div class="menu__effect"></div>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Один</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Два</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Три</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Четыре</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Пять</a>
  <a class="menu__item" href="#">Шесть</a>
  <div class="menu__effect"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, но "три" не должен быть все время красным

Comment: @ii5, уберите из HTML класс `menu__item--active`, он делался для того, что если какой-то пункт меню будет активным, то выделение у него будет изначально.

Answer (score 2):

Так?

```js
if (document.querySelector("#menu-wrapper")) {
  let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let menuLayerDown = document.createElement("span");
  menuLayerDown.classList.add("menu-layer-down");
  fragment.appendChild(menuLayerDown);
  document.querySelector(".menu-layer-up").before(fragment.cloneNode(true));
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".menu-layer-up")].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
    s.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let activeIndex = arr.indexOf(
        document.querySelector(".menu-layer-down").nextElementSibling
      );
      if (!s.previousElementSibling && activeIndex < i) {
        s.before(fragment.cloneNode(true));
        s.previousElementSibling.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
        setTimeout(() => {
          s.previousElementSibling.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
          arr[activeIndex].previousElementSibling.style.transform =
            "translateX(100%)";
          setTimeout(() => {
            arr[activeIndex].previousElementSibling.remove();
          }, 300);
        }, 1);
      } else {
        s.before(fragment.cloneNode(true));
        s.previousElementSibling.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
        setTimeout(() => {
          s.previousElementSibling.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
          arr[activeIndex].previousElementSibling.style.transform =
            "translateX(-100%)";
          setTimeout(() => {
            arr[activeIndex].previousElementSibling.remove();
          }, 100);
        }, 1);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/anonymouspro/v21/rP2Bp2a15UIB7Un-bOeISG3pHls28A.ttf) format('truetype');
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: url(../public/binary/image/svg/icon.svg), pointer;
}

html,
body {
  touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.custom {
  display: block;
}

#main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#main-wrapper #box-shadow {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#main-wrapper .box-shadow {
  animation: shadow 0.3s ease;
}

#main-wrapper .background-layer-down {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/931085/02db7f18-c93c-4297-9cf9-70002aefbd30/s1200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  filter: blur(7px);
}

#main-wrapper .background-layer-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper #iconWrapper {
  opacity: 0;
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper nav menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: transparent;
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper nav menu li {
  margin: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: "Anonymous Pro" monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-kerning: auto;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  background: transparent;
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper nav menu li .menu-layer-down {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ff3737;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper nav menu li span.menu-layer-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: block;
}

#main-wrapper #menu-wrapper nav menu li span.menu-layer-up:hover {
  color: #272727;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div class="background-layer-down"></div>
  <div class="background-layer-up"></div>
  <div id="menu-wrapper">
    <nav>
      <menu>
        <li><span class="menu-layer-up">MAIN</span></li>
        <li><span class="menu-layer-up">PORTFOLIO</span></li>
        <li><span class="menu-layer-up">CLIENTS</span></li>
        <li><span class="menu-layer-up">OUR PRICES</span></li>
        <li><span class="menu-layer-up">CONTACTS</span></li>
        <li><span class="menu-layer-up">ABOUT US</span></li>
      </menu>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```